# Insert Array in SQLite Database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I want to save weekdays in database, so i thought to store it by assigning int value to each day. i.e

**1** -> Selected,  **0** -> Not Selected.

Monday = 0/1

Tuesday = 0/1

.
.
.
.
.

Sunday = 0/1.

But this will make 7 columns in **DB**. So I was thinking if anyone can help me with this if I should store it in a single array and retrieve the values for further use. I was reading some examples over internet but didn't get it in a easy way.

Comment: if you want to store array in one column then put your all days value in json array and store it to in database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To insert 7 values in one column you can use comma separator like this

where Total_Score_P1 is an string array

//string array

```
String[]  Total_Score =  new String[] { p1e1,p1e2,p1e3,p1e4,p1e5,p1e6 };


// Convderting it into a single string 

String result_ScoreP1 = ("" + Arrays.asList(Total_Score_P1)).
             replaceAll("(^.|.$)", "  ").replace(", ", "  , " );
```

result_ScoreP1 will be

// output of this

```
result_ScoreP1 = "p1e1,p1e2,p1e3,p1e4,p1e5,p1e6";
```

insert it as a single string in database  and 
when retrieve it in again break in parts like

// a string array list

// query fired

```
public ArrayList<String> rulTable(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> Ruleob = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c_rule;

        try
        {
            c_rule = db.query(NameTable, new String[]{
                    columns1        
            },
            Rule_COurseID + "=" + id ,
                              null, null, 
                              null, null, null);

            c_rule.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
            // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
            if (!c_rule.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {

                    Ruleob.add(c_rule.getString(0));

                }
                while (c_rule.moveToNext());
            }

            // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
            c_rule.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {


        }
        return Ruleob;


    }


//list to get elements 

 ArrayList<String>  ListOne = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> row ;

    try{
// received values
        row = db.TheTable(id);
        String r1 = row .get(0);

}

catch(Exception e)

{

}


 StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(r1, "||");

            while(st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String Desc = st2.nextToken();
               System.out.println(Desc+ "\t" ); 
            ListOne.add(Desc); 

//   
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a binary integer 1= selected 0 =Not Selected (1111111) (0000000)

total seven days so index 0=mon, 1=tues, 2=wed, 3=thurs, 4=friday, 5=sat, 6=sunday..and so on..

here 1111111 means all day selected, 0000000 all day not selected, 0001000 only thursday is selected.

Comment: yah, i knw that, but it'll be a same thing as i am doing now, any idea if we can use array/arraylist in DB as I have to use those days to set Alarm ON in my app.

Comment: you can set Alarm by this concept, not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

I have also discovered a way i.e. convert your so called values to a **JSON Array** and then store the complete **JSON String** to an entity/field in Database.

It helps in serving the values easily and effectivly.

Answer (score 2):

Create another table with a column for each day, boolean value. Make an association to this table by integer id (use a foreign key) This is the relational way of solving the problem.